# Why the leaves of the Barbados cherry plant are turning yellow?

Tags: leaves, diseases, cherries

The leaves of my seven month old Barbados cherry plant are developing pale yellow spots, which then spread till covering the entire leaves. The spreading of the yellow spots to cover an entire leaf takes several months (2-3 months).

I wonder what may be causing this. There are no significant insect infestation in the plant.

**Yellow spots in the leaves at different stages**
[image: Yellow spots in the leaves at different stages]
**Some completely yellow leaves**
[image: Some completely yellow leaves]
**The whole plant**
[image: The whole plant]

The white things at the base of the plant are broken eggshells recently applied as calcium fertilizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically Yellowing of leaves is a sign of magnesium deficiency. The solution is to dissolve some epsom salt (magnesium sulfate) about a Tablespoon per gallon of water and apply to the plant in it's next watering.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Will try your suggestion and observe what happens.